# Local expression of a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensor-products, tensors, smooth-manifolds

During the course, we have defined differential forms as maps
$$
\omega : D(M) \times \cdots \times D(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^\infty(M),
$$
where $D(M)$ are the global derivates of the manifold $M$. I know that locally, a global derivate has the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a^i \partial/\partial x^i,
$$
where $x^1,...,x^n$ are the local coordinates and $a^i$ are $\mathcal{C^\infty}$ functions.

I don't understand why an antisymmetric $k$-differential form has this form in a neighbouhood $U$:
$$
\sum a_{i_1,...,i_k}dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}.
$$
Where $dx^i$ forms a basis of the covector space $T_pM^*$.

Said this... Locally, I understand that $\omega$ depends on the $\partial/\partial x^i$, so that the $a_{i_1,...,i_k}$ are determined but the action of omega on the $\partial/\partial x^i$, but I don't understand where the wedge product comes from.

If someone could illuminate me, I'd be thankful!

Comment: It's because differential $k$-forms are, by definition, antisymmetric tensors. The wedge product is how we build all antisymmetric tensors.

Comment: what you are witnessing  is a generalization of $dx^k\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\right)=\delta^k{}_l$.